# How can I create a distributable with CMake and C++?

Tags: c++, cmake, executable

I am trying to build a little executable based on ros that I can distribute to different Linux machines, it is fully functional on the machine I am developing it (Because it contains all the `*.so` files it has linked), but it fails to find them when I try to run the executable in another machine.

Is there a way to add these `.so` files to the executable or to create a compressed directory with all the necessary libs to be able to run this executable in any machine?

I am following [this tutorial](https://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29) and my `CMakeLists.txt` is an exact copy of [this one](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/catkin_tutorials/master/create_package_pubsub/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/CMakeLists.txt).

The software works fine, I just can't distribute it. Is it possible to do it?

Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Minimally**, you can use `cpack` (already as part of `cmake` when you installed it) by adding the following at the bottom-most of your `CMakeLists.txt`

```
...
install(TARGETS myapp
    RUNTIME
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
install(CODE "
    include(BundleUtilities)
    fixup_bundle(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/myapp \"\" \"\")
    ")
...
include(CPack)
```

The main thing is at [fixup_bundle](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.15/module/BundleUtilities.html) which will go through dependent libraries for you.

The workflow is as follows

1. Create a temporary build directory (assume we're at root source directory) `mkdir build`
2. `cd build`
3. `cmake ..`
4. `cpack`

Your result of binary executable (provided you already added such cmake command for this) along with `.so` files as we've done above will live inside `<project-source-root-dir>/bin` directory.

This doesn't fully utilize features provided by `cpack` just yet i.e. building `.tar.gz` file bundled with our selected files, or source code. But we could possibly simply include a custom script to process on resultant `bin/` directory which already packed with executable and shared library files.

### Test case

I tested against my own [simple program](https://github.com/haxpor/tt/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt) which depends on shared libraries of OpenSSL's SSL + Crypto component, and libcurl. Followed above steps. I got the following in my `bin/` directory.

```
libcrypto.so.1.1  libcurl.so  libssl.so.1.1  tt
```

And validate via `readelf -d <executable-file>` which I got

```
Dynamic section at offset 0x9be8 contains 30 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libcrypto.so.1.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libcurl.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libm.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several options:

1. Build all the static library dependencies, and then generate a single big statically linked executable.
2. Keep binary linking, and package your application with its  dependencies using the qt installer framework or an alternative like InstallBuilder.
3. Create distro independent packages: [Snappy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snappy_(package_manager)), [Flatpak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flatpak) or [AppImage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppImage).